# Date Format issue in CGridView - YII Framework

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I am trying to display created date column in CGridView, in DB its datatype is DateTime.
I have used the below code to format the date,

```
array(  'name'=>'created',
                        'header'=>'created',
        'value' => 'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d/M/y",strtotime($data->created))'
                       ),
```

I am getting date formated column in CGridView, but null values shows sysdate in column. Please see attached image,

Please provide any solution to remove sysdate in null values column

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `strtotime(null)` will return `false` (*Kami* is apparently wrong).

The issue is in Yii date formater : `Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d/M/y", false)` will return current date.

You should simply create a getter in your model :

```
function getCreatedDate()
{
  if ($this->created===null)
    return;

  return Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d/M/y", $this->created);
}
```

And in your grid view columns, you just have to use :

- `array('name'=>'created', 'value'=>'$data->createdDate')`,
- or `'createdDate'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nullDisplay](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#nullDisplay-detail) property of CGridView and set:

```
'nullDisplay'=>''
```